# How to get an artist's "also on" external links through Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Many popular artists now feature an automatically populated "Also on" widget on their Facebook pages. Is there a way to get those through the Graph API?

Facebook page examples:

- https://www.facebook.com/arminvanbuuren
- https://www.facebook.com/Thekillers

Answer (score 0):

I would have to say it's not available via the graph.  It appears that there's a widget that does the "Also On" features.

See: http://soshable.com/how-to-turn-off-the-also-on-feature-on-your-facebook-page/